# Least square optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, linear-regression, least-squares

I am wondering how one could solve the following problem in R.

We have a *v* vector (of *n* elements) and a *B* matrix (of dimension *m x n*).
E.g:

```
    > v 
    [1] 2 4 3 1 5 7

    > B
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
    [1,]    2    1   5    5    3    4
    [2,]    4    5   6    3    2    5
    [3,]    3    7   5    1    7    6
```

I am looking for the *m*-long vector *u* such that

```
    sum( ( v - ( u %*% B) )^2 )
```

is minimized (i.e. minimizes the sum of squares).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are describing linear regression, which can be done with the `lm` function:

```
coefficients(lm(v~t(B)+0))
#      t(B)1      t(B)2      t(B)3 
#  0.2280676 -0.1505233  0.7431653
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick and clear answer.
And what if I am looking for vector *u* such that
 sum( ( V - ( B%*%diag(u) %*%t( B)) )^2 ) is minimized (for fixed matrices V and B). It is very similar but I don't know whether lm function can also solve this problem.

Comment: @benny this sounds different enough that I would encourage you to ask a separate question. You can reference this question and answer if it makes it more clear.

Comment: Thank you, I asked it in a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301694/least-square-optimization-of-matrices-in-r