# Least square optimization (of matrices) in R

Tags: r, optimization, regression, least-squares

Yesterday I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268826/least-square-optimization-in-r/31269108) about least square optimization in R and it [turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268826/least-square-optimization-in-r/31269108#31269108) that `lm` function is the thing that I was looking for.

On the other hand, now I have an other least square optimization question and I am wondering if `lm` could also solve this problem, or if not, how it can be handled in R.

I have fixed matrices *B* (of dimension n x m) and *V* (of dimension n x n), I am looking for an *m*-long vector *u* such that

```
       sum( ( V - ( B %*% diag(u) %*% t(B)) )^2 )
```

is minimized.

Comment: How about using `optmatch`: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optmatch/index.html

Comment: You should post an example using either `dput` or R code that can be pasted into a console session to construct a suitable test case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) lm.fit** Use the fact that

vec(AXA') = (A ⊗ A ) vec(X)

so:

```
k <- ncol(A)
AA1 <- kronecker(A, A)[, c(diag(k)) == 1]
lm.fit(AA1, c(V))
```

Here is a self contained example:

```
# test data
set.seed(123)
A <- as.matrix(BOD)
u <- 1:2
V <- A %*% diag(u) %*% t(A) + rnorm(36)

# solve
k <- ncol(A)
AA1 <- kronecker(A, A)[, c(diag(k)) == 1]
fm1 <- lm.fit(AA1, c(V))
```

giving roughly the original coefficients 1:2 :

```
> coef(fm1)
      x1       x2 
1.011206 1.999575
```

**2) nls**   We can alternately use `nls` like this:

```
fm2 <- nls(c(V) ~ c(A %*% diag(x) %*% t(A)), start = list(x = numeric(k)))
```

giving the following for the above example:

```
> fm2
Nonlinear regression model
  model: c(V) ~ c(A %*% diag(x) %*% t(A))
   data: parent.frame()
   x1    x2 
1.011 2.000 
 residual sum-of-squares: 30.52

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.741e-09
```

**Update:** Corrections and second solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I set A <- matrix( rnorm(145*5,mean=0,sd=1), 145, 5) (and hence n =145) then I get the following error: 'Error in kronecker(A, A)[, c(diag(n)) == 1] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long'